# Symfony2 argument 1 passed must be a type of array, object given error

Tags: php, symfony

A simple problem that has many answers on SO... Yet none of them work on my project... So I get this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Dig\front\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 528 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Digidis\front\vendor\doctrine\collections\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 48
```

This happens everytime I create a new Email and try to save it in the database. The email is in a relationship with skin..

This is how I try to save it:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{skin_id}/new", name="cms_email_new")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction($skin_id) {
        $skin = $this->getRepository('ProjectSkinBundle:Skin')->find($skin_id);
        $item = new Email();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EmailType($this->container->getParameter("langs")), $item);

        return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'item' => $item, 'skin' => $skin_id);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{skin_id}/save", name="cms_email_save")
     * @Template("ProjectUserBundle:EmailAdmin:new.html.twig")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function saveAction(Request $request, $skin_id) {

        $skin = $this->getRepository('ProjectSkinBundle:Skin')->find($skin_id);
        $item = new Email();
        $type = new EmailType($this->container->getParameter("langs"));
        $form = $this->createForm($type, $item);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $this->upload($form, $item);

            $skin->setEmailId($item);
            $item->setSkin($skin);  /// the error is here
            $em->persist($skin);
            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_skin_email_edit', array('skin_id' => $skin_id)));
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'item' => $item);
    }
```

So by doing some testing I found out that this line is causing the problem:

```
$item->setSkin($skin);
```

Without this line everything works like a charm. However I need this line to work.

So this is the Entity with the setSkin method:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skin", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $skin;

    /**
     * Set skin
     *
     * @param \Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin $skin
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setSkin(\Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin $skin = null)
    {
        $this->skin = $skin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get skin
     *
     * @return \Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin
     */
    public function getSkin()
    {
        return $this->skin;
    }
```

So what can I do to make his object become an array?

I have this little line but id doesnt help me :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->skin = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The form for creating a new email is this:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {

        $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'));

}
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Project\UserBundle\Entity\Email',
    );
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'my_email';
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this line in the constructor:

    `$this->skin = new ArrayCollection();`

While the `setSkin` and `getSkin` function clearly use a `Skin` object.

Comment: That was just for testing... However with this line or not it doesnt work :)

Comment: I don't think the error is occurring where you think it is as this line isn't creating an ArrayCollection object. The line above appears wrong ($skin->setEmailId($item);), you are manually setting the email id rather than the relationship object (i.e. $skin->setEmail($item), but the id is being set to the entire object instead of $item->getId().

Comment: Actually no. setEmailId is actually setEmail just with the different naming. I will change that eventually. Without the setSkin the code works, and the skin has the id of the email assignet to it, however the email itself doesnt have the skin assigned.(because setSkin doesnt work.) The problem is that $skin is an object.. And I need it to be an array

Comment: @Dominykas55 You could find the answer faster by reading the documentation rather than posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$skin` property is a One to Many relationship in your doctrine mapping. Doctrine is expecting an `ArrayCollection` object or array.

This is causing your exception:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skin", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $skin;
```

If you need a one to many relationship you should pass an `array` instead of a single object because you can have multiple skins. If you want a one to one relationship (a single skin per entity) you should change you doctrine mapping.

Possible solution 1:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->skin = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Set skin
 *
 * @param \Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin $skin
 * @return Email
 */
public function setSkin(array $skin)
{
    $this->skin = $skin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get skin
 *
 * @return \Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin[]|ArrayCollection
 */
public function getSkin()
{
    return $this->skin;
}
```

Possible solution 2 (OneToOne, but this could be a ManyToOne, that's up to you):

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skin", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $skin;
```

Comment: In one to one you wolud always get array collection error when object is null .

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the error by simply wrapping the object (which you should confirm is an "Email" object) in an array:

```
$item->setSkin(array($skin));
```

**However** something else is going wrong here and the error is coming from when Doctrine compiles a unit-of-work to save to the database.

The skin relationship declartion of the Email entity is incorrect. The Join column declaration should be on the manyToOne side, so Email should be:

Email entity:

```
 /*
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email")
 */
 protected $skins;
```

Skin entity:

```
 /*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\SkinBundle\Entity\Email", inversedBy="emails")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $email
```

Running `app/console doctrine:generate:entities SkinBundle:Email` (or however the entity is referenced) will then generate a methods like `addSkin(Skin $skin)` which are used to add objects to the relationship.

More info can be found on [Doctrine associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).

Answer (score 0):

For a one to many relationship you should have and be using methods addSkin() and removeSkin() in place of setSkin(). Also, as a convention I recommend pluralising collection properties i.e. $skin -> $skins. It makes the code clearer and errors in declaring and using entities become more obvious.

So for your entity that has many $skins I would recommend:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $skins;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->skins = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add skin
 *
 * @param Skin $skin
 * @return Email
 */
public function addSkin(Skin $skin)
{
    $this->skins[] = $skin;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove skin
 *
 * @param Skin $skin
 */
public function removeSkin(Skin $skin)
{
    $this->skins->removeElement($skin);
}

/**
 * Get skins
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getSkins()
{
    return $this->skins;
}
```

Then where you have:

```
       $item->setSkin($skin);
```

You should instead use:

```
       $item->addSkin($skin);
```